# upgraded to Qt 5.7 but all references still point to 5.5.1

Tags: upgrade, qt

I installed Qt 5.7 followuing these instructions: https://wiki.qt.io/Install_Qt_5_on_Ubuntu to `/opt/Qt5.7.0` but all my Qt applications including `Qt Creator` still refer to my "old" version `5.5.1`. How do I replace my old version?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you confirm what you mean by "all my Qt applications"? Are you saying that applications you are developing with Qt Creator are using Qt 5.5.1?

Comment: `gsxruk yes and also and `qmake -v` gives me `Using Qt version 4.8.7`

Comment: If you open the options dialog in Qt Creator (Tools->Options using the menu), select "Build & Run" on the left hand side and then choose the "Kits" tab, could you list (or provide a screenshot) of the kits listed?